# Database returning empty result from dynamic-queries

Tags: 7, database

I have Tested the Query in PHPMyadmin and it work fine, then I use the [Query Coder Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_coder) to build the query but it keep returning empty. I still went back to use PHPMyAdmin to cross-check it work over their.

What am trying to archive is to pull data from Comment table and a field table linked to fiverstar, below is my SQL

```
SELECT SUM(`f`.`field_culture_rating`) AS total
FROM 
field_data_field_culture f
JOIN comment c ON c.cid = f.entity_id
WHERE  (f.entity_id = c.cid) AND (c.nid = 1)
```

Here is the Drupal Query

```
$query = db_select('field_data_field_culture', 'f');
$query->innerJoin('comment', 'c', 'c.cid = f.entity_id');
$query->addExpression('SUM(f.field_culture_rating)', 'total');
$query->fields('f', array('entity_id', 'field_culture_rating'));
$query->fields('c', array('cid', 'nid'));
$query->condition('f.entity_id', 'c.cid');
$query->condition('c.nid', 1);
```

The above produce:

```
SELECT f.entity_id AS entity_id, f.field_agriculture_rating AS field_agriculture_rating, c.cid AS cid, c.nid AS nid, SUM(f.field_agriculture_rating) AS total
FROM 
{field_data_field_agriculture} f
INNER JOIN {comment} c ON c.cid = f.entity_id
WHERE  (f.entity_id = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (c.nid = :db_condition_placeholder_1)
```

I have use both of these for output but still empty

```
$result = $query->execute()->fetchField();
$result = $query3->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

I dont know what am doing wrong

Comment: I think `$query->condition('f.entity_id', 'c.cid');` is redundant because this is the innerJoin condition, and it might be converting `c.cid` into a string and comparing it literally to that. And you won't have any entity_id values that equal to a string `'c.cid'`. Try to remove that and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes you are right, I don't know much about Database API, it was later I discover that the JOIN take three arguments, and the last arg which is the condition took care of the `$query->condition('f.entity_id', 'c.cid');`

thank you so much